# Loss of data in android handler transfers

Tags: android, android-fragments, bluetooth, data-transfer, data-synchronization

I have a system communicating with a Bluetooth target device, which sends a command string on an action on the Android system and receives data from the target on a clocked sequence.  There are no apparent problems with the outgoing data, but I am losing data intermittently between the Bluetooth service routine and the fragment where it is presented to the UI.

The communications path inside the Android application is:

- Bluetooth service routine as per the example. The first byte of the incoming data stream is used to indicate the type of information contained: this byte is stripped off and the remainder reassembled into a fixed-length byte array dataBuffer[]. This array is then returned to the host activity using mHandler.obtainMessage().

The relevant portion of code is:

```
/*
* This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
* It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
*/
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread 
{
   private static final byte enq = 5;
   private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
   private final InputStream mmInStream;
   private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

   public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) 
   {
       if (D) Log.d(TAG, "498 - create ConnectedThread: " + socketType);
       mmSocket = socket;
       InputStream tmpIn = null;
       OutputStream tmpOut = null;
     // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
       try 
       {
           tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
           tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
       } 
       catch (IOException e) 
       {
           Log.e(TAG, "510 - temp sockets not created", e);
       }
       mmInStream = tmpIn;
       mmOutStream = tmpOut;
   }

   public void run() 
   {
       if (D) Log.i(TAG, "518 - Begin mConnectedThread");
       int bytes;
       int dataCount = 0;
     // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
       while (true) 
       {
           try 
           {
             // Read from the InputStream
               byte[] inBuffer = new byte[128];
               int bufferPtr = 0;
               bytes = mmInStream.read(inBuffer);
               if (D) Log.e(TAG, "530 - InStream length = : " + bytes + " bytes: ");
               for (int i=0; i<bytes; i++)
               {
                   if (D) Log.e(TAG, "533 - inBuffer[" + i + "] - " + Integer.toHexString(inBuffer[i] & 0xFF) + " - " + (char)inBuffer[i] );
               }

               while(bufferPtr<bytes)
               {
//                 if (D) Log.e(TAG, " 538 - dataIn = " + dataIn + "  : ctlIn = " + ctlIn);
                   if (!dataIn && !ctlIn )
                   {
                       if (inBuffer[bufferPtr] == enq)              // Is it a new data message?
                       {
                           if (D) Log.e(TAG, "543 - New data stream in" );
                           dataIn = true;
                           Arrays.fill(dataBuffer,(byte)0);
                           bufferPtr++;
                           dataCount = 0;
                       }
                       else                         // Must be a new control command
                       {
                           // It's a control message
                       }
                   }
                   if (dataIn && (bufferPtr<bytes))
                   {
                       if (dataCount<dataItems)
                       {
                           dataBuffer[dataCount] = inBuffer[bufferPtr];
                           dataCount++;
                           bufferPtr++;
                           if(D) Log.e(TAG, "565 - dataBuffer[" + (dataCount-1) +"] - " + Integer.toHexString(dataBuffer[dataCount-1] & 0xFF));
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           dataIn = false;
                           for (int i=0; i<dataBuffer.length; i++)
                           {
                               if (D) Log.e(TAG, "573 - DataInArray[" + i + "] = " + Integer.toHexString(dataBuffer[i] & 0xFF));
                           }
                           mHandler.obtainMessage(BaseActivity.DATA_MESSAGE_IN, dataBuffer.length, -1, dataBuffer).sendToTarget();
                           if (D) Log.e(TAG, "576 - " + dataItems + " bytes received. Data stream sent to host ##" );
                       }
                   }
                   if (ctlIn)
                   {
                       // It'a control message                         
                   }
               }
               // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
           } 
           catch (IOException e) 
           {
               Log.e(TAG, "604 - disconnected", e);
               connectionLost();
               // Start the service over to restart listening mode
               BtService.this.start();
               break;
           }
       }
   }
```

- The incoming data stream is passed back to the base activity, where it is used to build a byte array dataIn[] - this array is then passed directly on to the Fragment for display. (I want eventually to be able redirect the incoming data to different Fragments.)

The Handler code in the base activity is:

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
{
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "427 - << Handler message received: >> " + msg.what);
    switch (msg.what) 
    {
        case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                // Deal with state change
                break;

            case MESSAGE_OUT:
                // Deal with outgoing message
                break;

            case CONTROL_MESSAGE_IN:
                // Deal with incoming control message
                break;

            case DATA_MESSAGE_IN:
                dataIn = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                int dataMsgLength = msg.arg1;
                if (D) Log.e(TAG, "490 - Received data stream: length = " + msg.arg1 + " bytes:");
                for (int i=0; i<dataMsgLength; i++)
                {
                    if (D) Log.e(TAG, "494 - DataIn[" + i + "] - " + Integer.toHexString(dataIn[i] & 0xFF));
                }
                Hmi2Fragment.updateDisplay(dataIn);
                break;

            case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                // save the connected device's name
                break;

            case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                // Deal with Toast
                break;

            case FILE_SELECTED:
                // Deal with file
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

- The received data array is then passed on to the Fragment Hmi2 , where it is displayed.  The code for this is:
  // Method called by host activity to update the displayed data.
  public static void updateDisplay(byte[] inDataBytes)
  {
      for (int i=0; i

  ```
          if ((k & 2) != 0) bst[1].setImageLevel(1);
          else bst[1].setImageLevel(0);
          bst[1].invalidate();
      }
      else
      {
          for (int j=0; j<8; j++)
          {
              int indNo = mapIn[i-1][j];
              if ((indNo == 0) || (indNo >0))
              {
                  if ((k & (1 << j)) != 0) ind[indNo].setImageLevel(1);
                  else  ind[indNo].setImageLevel(0);
                  ind[indNo].invalidate();
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

The problem is that, when I run the app and use Logcat to trace the data flow through the pipeline, the arrays are not tracking each other as I expect.

An example of a good transfer is:

```
10-04 09:09:14.643  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   530 - InStream length = 1 bytes
10-04 09:09:14.643  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[0] - 5 -  
10-04 09:09:14.643  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[0] = 1
10-04 09:09:14.643  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[1] = 95
10-04 09:09:14.643  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[2] = 0
10-04 09:09:14.643  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[3] = 18
10-04 09:09:14.653  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[4] = 2
10-04 09:09:14.653  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[5] = e4
10-04 09:09:14.653  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[6] = 2
10-04 09:09:14.653  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[7] = 0
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[8] = 0
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[9] = 0
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[10] = 0
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   576 - 11 bytes received. Data stream sent to host ##
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   543 - New data stream in
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   530 - InStream length = 11 bytes
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[0] - 1 -  
10-04 09:09:14.673  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[1] - 95 - ﾕ
10-04 09:09:14.673  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[2] - 0 - ��
10-04 09:09:14.673  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[3] - 3a - :
10-04 09:09:14.673  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[4] - 2 -  
10-04 09:09:14.673  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[5] - e3 - ￣
10-04 09:09:14.673  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[6] - 2 -  
10-04 09:09:14.673  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[7] - 0 - ��
10-04 09:09:14.673  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[8] - 0 - ��
10-04 09:09:14.673  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[9] - 0 - ��
10-04 09:09:14.673  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[10] - 0 - ��
10-04 09:09:14.673  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[0] - 1
10-04 09:09:14.673  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[1] - 95
10-04 09:09:14.673  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[2] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.673  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[3] - 3a
10-04 09:09:14.673  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[4] - 2
10-04 09:09:14.683  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[5] - e3
10-04 09:09:14.683  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[6] - 2
10-04 09:09:14.683  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[7] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.683  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[8] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.683  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[9] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.683  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[10] - 0

10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C Base(4304)    427 - << Handler message received >> 4
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C Base(4304)    490 - Received data stream  length = 11 bytes:
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[0] - 1
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[1] - 95
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[2] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[3] - 18
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[4] - 2
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[5] - e4
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[6] - 2
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[7] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[8] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[9] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[10] - 0

10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[0] - 1
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[1] - 95
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[2] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[3] - 18
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[4] - 2
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[5] - e4
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[6] - 2
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[7] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[8] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[9] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.663  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[10] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.683  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    295 - i = 0  lsb = 58 msb = 2
10-04 09:09:14.683  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    297 - val[0] = 55.0
10-04 09:09:14.683  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    295 - i = 1  lsb = 227 msb = 2
10-04 09:09:14.683  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    297 - val[1] = 72.0
10-04 09:09:14.683  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    295 - i = 2  lsb = 0 msb = 0
10-04 09:09:14.683  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    297 - val[2] = -1.0
10-04 09:09:14.693  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    295 - i = 3  lsb = 0 msb = 0
10-04 09:09:14.693  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    297 - val[3] = -1.0
```

An example of a failure between the base activity and the Fragment is:

```
10-04 09:09:14.883  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   530 - InStream length = 1 bytes
10-04 09:09:14.883  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[0] - 5 -  
10-04 09:09:14.893  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[0] = 1
10-04 09:09:14.893  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[1] = 95
10-04 09:09:14.893  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[2] = 0
10-04 09:09:14.893  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[3] = 3a
10-04 09:09:14.893  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[4] = 2
10-04 09:09:14.893  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[5] = e3
10-04 09:09:14.893  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[6] = 2
10-04 09:09:14.893  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[7] = 0
10-04 09:09:14.903  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[8] = 0
10-04 09:09:14.903  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[9] = 0
10-04 09:09:14.903  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[10] = 0
10-04 09:09:14.913  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   576 - 11 bytes received. Data stream sent to host ##
10-04 09:09:14.913  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   543 - New data stream in
10-04 09:09:14.923  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   530 - InStream length = 11 bytes
10-04 09:09:14.923  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[0] - 1 -  
10-04 09:09:14.923  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[1] - 95 - ﾕ
10-04 09:09:14.923  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[2] - 0 - ��
10-04 09:09:14.923  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[3] - 59 - Y
10-04 09:09:14.923  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[4] - 2 -  
10-04 09:09:14.923  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[5] - e4 - ￤
10-04 09:09:14.923  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[6] - 2 -  
10-04 09:09:14.933  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[7] - 0 - ��
10-04 09:09:14.933  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[8] - 0 - ��
10-04 09:09:14.933  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[9] - 0 - ��
10-04 09:09:14.933  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[10] - 0 - ��
10-04 09:09:14.933  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[0] - 1
10-04 09:09:14.943  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[1] - 95
10-04 09:09:14.943  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[2] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.943  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[3] - 59
10-04 09:09:14.943  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[4] - 2
10-04 09:09:14.943  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[5] - e4
10-04 09:09:14.943  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[6] - 2
10-04 09:09:14.943  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[7] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.953  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[8] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.953  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[9] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.953  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[10] - 0

10-04 09:09:14.903  E/C&C Base(4304)    427 - << Handler message received >> 4
10-04 09:09:14.903  E/C&C Base(4304)    490 - Received data stream length = 11 bytes:
10-04 09:09:14.903  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[0] - 1
10-04 09:09:14.903  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[1] - 95
10-04 09:09:14.903  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[2] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.903  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[3] - 3a
10-04 09:09:14.903  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[4] - 2
10-04 09:09:14.913  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[5] - e3
10-04 09:09:14.913  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[6] - 2
10-04 09:09:14.913  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[7] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.913  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[8] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.913  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[9] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.913  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[10] - 0

10-04 09:09:14.913  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[0] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.913  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[1] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.913  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[2] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.913  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[3] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.923  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[4] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.923  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[5] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.923  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[6] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.933  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[7] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.933  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[8] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.933  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[9] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.933  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[10] - 0
10-04 09:09:14.973  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    295 - i = 0  lsb = 89 msb = 2
10-04 09:09:14.973  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    297 - val[0] = 58.0
10-04 09:09:14.973  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    295 - i = 1  lsb = 228 msb = 2
10-04 09:09:14.973  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    297 - val[1] = 72.0
10-04 09:09:14.983  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    295 - i = 2  lsb = 0 msb = 0
10-04 09:09:14.983  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    297 - val[2] = -1.0
10-04 09:09:14.983  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    295 - i = 3  lsb = 0 msb = 0
10-04 09:09:14.983  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    297 - val[3] = -1.0
```

and for loss of data between the Service and the activity:

```
10-04 09:09:16.453  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   530 - InStream length = 2 bytes
10-04 09:09:16.453  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[0] - 5 -  
10-04 09:09:16.453  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[1] - 1 -  
10-04 09:09:16.453  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[0] = 1
10-04 09:09:16.453  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[1] = 95
10-04 09:09:16.453  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[2] = 0
10-04 09:09:16.463  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[3] = ed
10-04 09:09:16.463  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[4] = 2
10-04 09:09:16.463  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[5] = e4
10-04 09:09:16.463  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[6] = 2
10-04 09:09:16.463  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[7] = 0
10-04 09:09:16.463  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[8] = 0
10-04 09:09:16.463  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[9] = 0
10-04 09:09:16.463  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   573 - DataInArray[10] = 0
10-04 09:09:16.463  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   576 - 11 bytes received. Data stream sent to host ##
10-04 09:09:16.463  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   543 - New data stream in
10-04 09:09:16.463  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[0] - 1
10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   530 - InStream length = 10 bytes
10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[0] - 95 - ﾕ
10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[1] - 0 - ��
10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[2] - d - 
10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[3] - 3 -  
10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[4] - e4 - ￤
10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[5] - 2 -  
10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[6] - 0 - ��
10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[7] - 0 - ��
10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[8] - 0 - ��
10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   533 - inBuffer[9] - 0 - ��
10-04 09:09:16.483  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[1] - 95
10-04 09:09:16.483  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[2] - 0
10-04 09:09:16.483  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[3] - d
10-04 09:09:16.483  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[4] - 3
10-04 09:09:16.483  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[5] - e4
10-04 09:09:16.483  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[6] - 2
10-04 09:09:16.483  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[7] - 0
10-04 09:09:16.483  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[8] - 0
10-04 09:09:16.483  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[9] - 0
10-04 09:09:16.483  E/C&C Bluetooth(4304)   565 - dataBuffer[10] - 0

10-04 09:09:16.463  E/C&C Base(4304)    427 - << Handler message received >> 4
10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C Base(4304)    490 - Received data stream length = 11 bytes:
10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[0] - 1
10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[1] - 0
10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[2] - 0
10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[3] - 0
10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[4] - 0
10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[5] - 0
10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[6] - 0
10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[7] - 0
10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[8] - 0
10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[9] - 0
10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C Base(4304)    494 - DataIn[10] - 0

10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[0] - 1
10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[1] - 0
10-04 09:09:16.473  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[2] - 0
10-04 09:09:16.483  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[3] - 0
10-04 09:09:16.483  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[4] - 3
10-04 09:09:16.483  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[5] - e4
10-04 09:09:16.483  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[6] - 2
10-04 09:09:16.483  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[7] - 0
10-04 09:09:16.483  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[8] - 0
10-04 09:09:16.483  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[9] - 0
10-04 09:09:16.483  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    260 - inDataBytes[10] - 0
10-04 09:09:16.493  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    295 - i = 0  lsb = 13 msb = 3
10-04 09:09:16.493  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    297 - val[0] = 76.0
10-04 09:09:16.493  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    295 - i = 1  lsb = 228 msb = 2
10-04 09:09:16.493  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    297 - val[1] = 72.0
10-04 09:09:16.493  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    295 - i = 2  lsb = 0 msb = 0
10-04 09:09:16.493  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    297 - val[2] = -1.0
10-04 09:09:16.493  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    295 - i = 3  lsb = 0 msb = 0
10-04 09:09:16.493  E/C&C HMI2(4304)    297 - val[3] = -1.0
```

It seems to me as if there is an issue with synchronising somewhere, but I cannot see any obvious ways in which the data could be disappearing.

EDIT: It's definitely a synch issue - deleting the arrays.fill command stops the problem as the byte array is updated rather than cleared and reloaded.
Any suggestions will be welcome!